# EF ObjectQuery<T> query = ObjectSet; So close

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

In my RepositoryBase within the DAL I have the code below...I can't seem to figure out ObjectQuery query = ObjectSet;   ? Am I close?

```
public IEnumerable<T> QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, params string[] children)
    {
        //ObjectQuery<T> query = ObjectSet;  //nope...requires 1 type argument
        //ObjectQuery<T> query = ObjectSet<T>; //nope......type used like variable
        // ObjectQuery<T> query = ObjectSet<T>(); //nope ...type used like variable
        //ObjectQuery<T> query = new ObjectSet<T>(); //nope...no constructors defined
        IQueryable<T> query;

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            query = query.Include(child);
        }

        return query.Where(filter);
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your should query on already instantiated ObjectSet not create it.

Comment: ..and "What do you want to achieve?"...look at the signature...look that I'm including child tables and applying a filter. all in a generic repository base.

Comment: This seems to NOT throw errors...if helpful to anyone     public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> QueryObjectGraph(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, params string[] children)
        {
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                dbset.Include(child);
            }

            return dbset.Where(filter);
        }

Comment: Just a friendly word of advice, saying things like *"Comments like this make me want to smash people"* and tacking on "??????????" and "?????!!!!!!!" to the end of comments doesn't really help your case when interacting with other users who are genuinely trying to help out.

Comment: You think I talk to people like that for no reason...comments were moderated.

Answer (score 3):

Chill out man. Didn't mean to sound rude. You just don't know what you are doing. If you look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx you see that ObjectSet is ObjectQuery so assignment does work. But you have to have ObjectSet created first!

"Since I am the expert"

Look amazingly this code works

```
using (var ctx = new ModelContainer())
{
    ObjectQuery<Person> objectQuery = ctx.People;
}
```

and type of ctx.People is ObjectSet

What is ObjectSet commented out in your code? Where it is created?

Comment: If I knew 100% what I was doing I wouldn't be asking a question here. I'll take care of it myself.

Comment: If you notice it's in quotes. I don't consider myself expert in EF. Wish I was! But the commented code has nothing to do with EF. In order to work with object (ObjectSet here) you have to have it created first. These are basics of programming. Commented code shows that you lack basic knowledge of any programming language.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with EF. But you don't understand it.

Comment: I see you edited your comment. I remember you were threatening me before. I'm done with you.